# Kanji form of "どうしました"?

Tags: word-usage

I have come across a sentence in anime

> 夜神くん**どうしました**？

that apparently translates to

> Yagami-kun, is there anything wrong?

But I am having trouble parsing what "どう" means in this context? Does anyone know what its kanji form is here? Apparently it's a word that combines with する to form some notion of "what's wrong?". I went through all of the dictionary words associated with "どう", but was unable one that made sense (though I'm very new to Japanese).

Comment: I think it would be 如何 but it is very rare

Comment: it seems like you're parsing どう as on'yomi, but it's not a chinese loanword. Is that why you're assuming it must have some kanji?
(as noted by George above, 如何 is rarely used, but is a much latter ateji, rather than etymologically derived.)

Comment: I just remember when I started Japanese that I thought that "everything" can be written in kanji - but I found that's not how it works. どう has been handled here, but what about  為る?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The どう here is the indeterminate counterpart to immediate (right nearby, closer to the speaker) こう, proximate (nearby, closer to the listener) そう, and distal (far away from both speaker and listener) ああ.

- こう → like this, in this manner
- そう → like that, in that manner
- ああ → like that over there, in the manner of that over there
- どう → like what, in what manner → how

In English, we idiomatically ask ***what** happened?* to inquire about an event.

In Japanese, we idiomatically ask **どう**しました? (literally *"**how** did it do?"*) to inquire about an event.

This is just another way in which the two languages differ.  When learning any new language, we have to learn the different individual words -- **and** we have to learn the "style" or idiom of how each language puts those words together.

---

**UPDATE:** To respond directly to the original question as asked, *"Does anyone know what its kanji form is here?"*:

As noted in the comments, there is a rare kanji spelling 如何.  I am more accustomed to seeing this used to spell synonym *ikaga* instead of *dō*, but it has historically been used for both.

That said, in everyday Japanese, there isn't any kanji spelling in common use.